# XML defined by two XSD files - a header and body

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am currently trying to use Java to unmarshall an XML provided by a url.

The problem is that it is defined by two XSD files; a header and a body.

```
<Document xmlns="http://some.url.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<DocHeader>
<CreatedAt>2014-07-09T09:01:15</CreatedAt>
</DocHeader>
<DocBody>
....some data
</DocBody>
</Document>
```

Now this xml is defined by two XSD files.

DocHeader.xsd and DocBody.xsd.

How should I combine these two xsd files in order to unmarshall the xml document?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a silly mistake: I was using the wrong root XSD.

As such, the solution was to define a root XSD containing the DocHeader.xsd and the DocBody.xsd as components.